# How to get the email id of each user who sent the message in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am new to Firebase and want to get the email id of each user and display it next to the message. I came across the code I have attached below and am able to get the photourl of each user and display it next to each users message and want tot get the email Id now

```
function Chat() {
  const scroll = useRef()
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  // var email = firebase.auth().currentUser && firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
  useEffect(() => {
      db.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
            
     })
  }, [])
  return (
      <div>
          <SignOut />
          <div className="msgs">
              {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL, uid , emailid}) => (
                  <div>
                      <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received'}`}>
                          <img style={{  width: "40px", height: "40px",margin: "2px 5px",borderRadius:"50%"}} 
                          src={photoURL} alt="" />
                          {emailid}
                          <p>{text}</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              ))}
          </div>
          <SendMessage scroll={scroll} />
          <div ref={scroll}></div>
      </div>
```

```
function SendMessage({ scroll }) {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')

  async function sendMessage(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      const { uid, photoURL, emailid } = auth.currentUser

      await db.collection('messages').add({
          text: msg,
          photoURL,
          uid,
         
          createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
      setMsg('')
      scroll.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
  return (
      <div>
                  {/* <input style={{ maxWidth: "1000px", fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', marginLeft: '25px', marginBottom: '-3px' }} placeholder='Message...' type="text" value={msg} onChange={e => setMsg(e.target.value)} /> */}
                
      
          <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
              {/* <div className="sendMsg"> */}
                 <div className="input1">
                 </div>
                  <input style={{maxWidth: "1000px",color:"white", background: "rgb(59, 59, 59)", width: "800px", fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', marginLeft: '25px', marginBottom: '-3px' }} placeholder='Message...' type="text" value={msg} onChange={e => setMsg(e.target.value)} />
                  

                  <button style={{ width: '20%', fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', margin: '4px 5% -13px 5%', maxWidth: '200px', color:"white"}} type="submit">Send</button>

              {/* </div> */}
          </form>
      </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

auth().currentUser.email will give the current email then I get that in the SendMessage component and then display it in the Chat component, go through the components it will be clear

```
function Chat() {
const scroll = useRef()
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
// var email = firebase.auth().currentUser && firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
   
   })
}, [])
return (
    <div>
        <SignOut />
        <div className="msgs">
            {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL, uid , email}) => (
                <div>
                    <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received'}`}>
                    <p>{email}</p> <br></br>
                        <img style={{  width: "40px", height: "40px",margin: "2px 5px",borderRadius:"50%"}} 
                        src={photoURL} alt="" /><br></br>
                      
                        <p>{text}</p><br></br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <SendMessage scroll={scroll} />
        <div ref={scroll}></div>
    </div>
)
```

}

```
function SendMessage({ scroll }) {
const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')

async function sendMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { uid, photoURL, email } = auth.currentUser

    await db.collection('messages').add({
        text: msg,
        photoURL,
        uid,
        email,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
    setMsg('')
    scroll.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}
return (
    <div>
                {/* <input style={{ maxWidth: "1000px", fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', marginLeft: '25px', marginBottom: '-3px' }} placeholder='Message...' type="text" value={msg} onChange={e => setMsg(e.target.value)} /> */}
              
    
        <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
            {/* <div className="sendMsg"> */}
               <div className="input1">
               </div>
                <input style={{maxWidth: "1000px",color:"white", background: "rgb(59, 59, 59)", width: "800px", fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', marginLeft: '25px', marginBottom: '-3px' }} placeholder='Message...' type="text" value={msg} onChange={e => setMsg(e.target.value)} />
                

                <button style={{ width: '20%', fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', margin: '4px 5% -13px 5%', maxWidth: '200px', color:"white"}} type="submit">Send</button>

            {/* </div> */}
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

}